# Help deploying using Capistrano to HostGator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-hosting, cpanel

My company uses HostGator to host our web sites, and I'm having a heck of a time figuring out what my final steps are to get a functioning RoR app up there.

I've got all the way up to configuring mongrel (I think?) and being able to run deploy:cold without any errors. However, I can't seem to get the app to show up in the designated CPanel area (HG says the name "current" is already reserved for another application), and I'm not sure which port was allowed for me to use. I've opened tickets with Customer Support just to be told that "You can't access the database with root"... Totally unrelated to my question...

So I think I'm in the final stretch and if anyone has any insight or experience with HostGator, please cue me in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if such 'shared hosting' accounts is the best way to approach this.  Instead I would suggest a vps account into which you can SSH in directly and setup a Linux distro of your choice - the most hassle free solution would be Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (or the newer 10.10).

Look at setting up Passenger + Apache.  Getting Capistrano to work after that is very simple, as deploy:cold simply has it login to your app server and pull on the code from your code repo.

Have you been able to log in and verify that deploy:cold has worked?  Check out this link as well: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/how-do-i-start-using-ruby-on-rails

Cheers, M.